# Understanding Floating point arithmetic

Tags: book-recommendation, floating-point

I really am in need of understanding floating point arithmetic, and I need an indepth knowledge of floating point arithmetic. The behaviour of most books that just *touch* the subject is [like described in here in this page](http://fabiensanglard.net/floating_point_visually_explained/). But honestly even the concept in the site, I found to be similar to the problem.

So, I need a book that goes on explaining the concepts of the number system that describe everything that is needed to understand floating point arithmetic, that lays a foundation of all the requirements like: excess-127 code.
(Basically I quit my book when I did not understand from where the E-127 came in the exponent of 2 in the floating point representation and weird terms like 1-plus form when I've never heard of it. Books that are not meant for entirely floating points don't clearly explain such concepts.)

Comment: Have a look at http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/Handbook.html
and the links on that page.

Comment: @DavidK , it's some kind of excess code(don't know what that is.). The explanation is technical in the book and so long, I don't know how much to write in the question. There's this confusion from normalization of floating points to this floating point representation in the book by W. Cheney that extend more that 3 pages and I don't have a clue.

Comment: Floating-point numbers are meant to allow computers to do computations like the ones that pure mathematics does with the real numbers. Since there are uncountably many real numbers and only a finite number of possible sequences of 32 bits (or even 64 or 128 bits), it is quite a challenge to select exactly which real numbers should be represented by sequences of bits and how such a sequence of bits should define a real number. In the process of doing this, computer scientists had to make use of several ideas that are not used (at least, not much used) elsewhere in mathematics.

Comment: So when your book says "excess-127," the meaning of "excess-whatever" is something that was _invented_ to deal with floating-point numbers in computers, and when you first see it used, you're probably looking at the _definition_ of what "excess-127" means. Similarly, the concept of adding 1 + a fraction as part of the interpretation of a floating-point number was an optimization to get one more bit's worth of precision out of a floating-point number. As in a lot of mathematics, a lot can happen in three pages, and you need to pick through it one step at a time.

Comment: Maybe a book is not primarily what you need? I am an engineering type who learns best by practical application and experimentation. My eyes often glaze over when I read publications with lots of mathematical notation. I learned floating-point arithmetic as a student by writing an emulator for basic floating-point operations, mostly based on short descriptions in computer manuals. For each concept (e.g. rounding) it took me weeks to get a good grasp of it. Later in life, I helped build floating-point processors and math libraries as part of my work as an engineer in the computer industry :-)

Comment: @njuffa , I do need the understanding. I do want to learn but not getting nice enough resources, just like the [owl](http://fabiensanglard.net/floating_point_visually_explained/) issue above.

Comment: @mathmaniage I get it. You *need* the understanding, I *wanted* the understanding of FP arithmetic. But I have a terrible time developing a thorough understanding of technical issues from frontal presentation (e.g. university lecture) or reading (books and articles) alone. Maybe you are in the same boat as me in that you need to use a different access path to the brain (e.g. hands-on experimentation) to develop this needed understanding? Besides J.-M. Muller's Handbook already recommended above maybe take a look at M. Overton, Numerical Computing with IEEE Floating Point Arithmetic.

Comment: @njuffa , thanks, I'll try those.